# Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError:

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony3.4, the following error occurred while supporting automatic wiring.
No particular changes have been made to the relevant parts.
Should I do something?

Postscript:
There was a place in services.yml that specified the service of the corresponding part.
Changing this part seems to solve the problem, but I can't think of a plan.

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html

Error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError:
Type error: Argument 2 passed to 
App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Listener\AdminExceptionListener::onKernelException() must implement interface 
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface, string given, called in 
/home/vagrant/Symfony2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php on line 115 in 
/home/vagrant/Symfony2/src/Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Listener/AdminExceptionListener.php:24
```

AdminExceptionListener.php

```php
namespace App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

/**
 * Management screen exception listener
 */
class AdminExceptionListener
{
    private $templating;
    private $container;
    public function __construct($templating, $container)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->container = $container;
    }
    //line24
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event, KernelInterface $kernel)  
    {
        // Default exception handling in debug mode
        if ($kernel->isDebug()) {
            return;
        }

        // Handle only exceptions that occur on the management screen
        if (!preg_match('/^\/admin\//', $event->getRequest()->getPathInfo())) {
            return;
        }
        ...
     }
}
```

services.yml

```yaml
services:
  # this makes public all the services defined in this file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    App\:
        resource: '../../src/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/{ Entity,Repository }'

    App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Listener\AdminExceptionListener:
      arguments: ['@templating', '@service_container']
      tags:
        - {
            name: kernel.event_listener,
            event: kernel.exception,
            method: onKernelException,
          }
```

Comment: you should inject the kernel in the construct directly, it should fix your problem (i've no idea what the autowire is trying to inject right now, a string but which one...)

Comment: @Snroki Thanks for your comment. I see, you should put kernel and GetResponseForExceptionEvent in __construct (). It was in this form before the update, so I didn't have any doubts. Also, please check the description of the relevant part in services.yml just in case.

Comment: @Snroki When I tried it, I got an error saying that there is no service for GetResponseForExceptionEvent. When I add a service to services.yml, I get an error saying that there is no different service (Requrest). Did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by passing only KernelInterface to __construct. Thanks to Snroki.

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;

/**
 */
class AdminExceptionListener
{
    protected $templating;
    protected $kernel;
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel, ContainerInterface $container, EngineInterface $templating)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        if ($this->kernel->isDebug()) {
            return;
        }
```